# Unequal fonts between TikZ graph and body text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to standardize the appearance of fonts since they appear in one way in the text, i.e.

[image]

and in another way on the graph, i.e.

[image: "On the graph.png"]

?

Here is the code:

```
%** MainS.tex**
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}  
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,spy,positioning,patterns}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

Let's consider the vector $\bm{\hat{x}}$ of the following figure
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=8, size=5.75cm, connect spies}] 

\draw [line width=.005pt,-{Latex[width=.25pt, length=.55pt]}] (9.83,6.67) -- ++(.22,.015)
node[pos=0.7,inner
sep=.25pt,above]{\fontsize{.75}{20}\selectfont $\bm{\hat{x}}$}; %X

\spy [red] on (10.095,6.725) in node at (15,2.7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The vector $\bm{\hat{x}}$.}
\label{fig:vectx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You use `\fontsize{.75}{20}\selectfont` and `spy`, so it is not too surprising that the fonts get modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing fontsize is not the same as scaling. If you want scaling, you can use `\scalebox` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
   /node{$\bm{\hat{x}}$};
   /node{\scalebox{0.5}{$\bm{\hat{x}}$}};
   /node{\fontsize{.75}{20}\selectfont $\bm{\hat{x}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Xxx]

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)